# How to highlight the search text in AngularJs 1.4.8 with a multi-dimensional array list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Here are my three files: .html, .js and .json file

Currently, I'm able to fetch and search from the JSON data, but I'm unable to highlight the searched data. I'm not getting any errors as well But, I'm unable to go further in the implementation.

I have attached all the required files in this post.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller('technologiesCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log, $location) {
        $http.get("../../angular/js/electrician.json").then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data.electrician;
            $log.info("new value:", $scope.myData);
            $scope.currentColor = "electrical";
        });
        $scope.currentSuburb = "Prospect"; 
    });
    app.config(function($sceProvider) {
      // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
      // Do not use in new projects or libraries.
      $sceProvider.enabled(false);
    });

    app.filter('highlightMatch', function($sce) {
    return function(words, data) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(data ? words.replace(new RegExp(`(${data})`, 'i'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>') : words);
    }
});
```

JSON File :

```
{
  "electrician": [
    {
      "title": {
          "name": "GENERAL ELECTRICAL",
          "bckColour": "electrical"
      },
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/general-electrical.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Smoke Alarm Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/smoke-alarm-installation-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Power Points Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/power-points-installation-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "3 in 1 Heater Fan Light Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/3-in-1-bathroom-heater-light-fan-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "LED dimmers Propsect",
        "url": "../../electrical/led-dimmers-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "ELECTRICAL EMERGENCY",
        "bckColour": "electrical"  
      },
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/electrical-emergency.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Power Failure Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/power-failure-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "House Rewiring Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/house-rewiring-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Electrical Emergency",
        "url": "../../electrical/emergency-electrician-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "Power Emergencies",
        "url": "../../electrical/power-failure-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "LIGHTING",
        "bckColour": "electrical" 
      },
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/lighting.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "LED Lighting Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/led-lighting-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Sensor Light Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/install-sensor-light-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Interior Lighting Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/interior-lighting-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "Outdoor Lighting Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/outdoor-lighting-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "DATA & SECURITY",
        "bckColour": "data" 
      }, 
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/data&security.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/digital-antennas-adelaide-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Home Security Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/home-security-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Digital TV Reception Prospect",
        "url": "../../tv-and-data/digital-tv-reception-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Interior Lighting Prospect",
        "url": "../../tv-and-data/foxtel-for-multiple-rooms-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "Digital TV Antennas Prospect",
        "url": "../../tv-and-data-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "ELECTRICAL SAFETY",
        "bckColour": "electrical" 
      }, 
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/electrical-safety.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Safety Switch Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/safety-switch-installation-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Switchboard Upgrades Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/switchboard-upgrades-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Electrical Inspection Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/electrical-inspection-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "Fuse Box Repairs Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/fuse-box-repairs-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "COMMERCIAL",
        "bckColour": "electrical" 
      },
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/commercial.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Backup Generators Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/backup-generator-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Office Fitouts Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/office-fitouts-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Shop Fitouts Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/shop-fitouts-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "UPS and Generators Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/ups-and-generators-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "CEILING FANS",
        "bckColour": "electrical" 
      }, 
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/ceiling-fan.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Ceiling Fans Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/ceiling-fans-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Ventilation Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/ventilation-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Exhaust Fans Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/exhaust-fans-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "Axial Fans Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/axial-fans-prospect/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "name": "ELECTRIC COOKING",
        "bckColour": "electrical"  
      },
      "img": "../../angular/images/electrical/electric-cooking.jpg",
      "imgurl":"../../diagnose-repair-install/electrical-installations-prospect/",
      "item1": {
        "name": "Cooktop Installation Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/cooktop-installation-prospect/"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "Oven installation Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/oven-installation-prospect/"
      },
      "item3": {
        "name": "Electric Hotplates Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/electric-hotplates-prospect/"
      },
      "item4": {
        "name": "Oven Repairs Prospect",
        "url": "../../electrical/oven-repairs-prospect/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../angular/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../angular/js/sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../../angular/js/sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../../angular/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../angular/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="technologiesCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br/>
        <div class="container-fluid img-responsive heroImage">
            <h1 class="pageHeader">Electrical Master Menu - {{currentSuburb}}</h1>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-inline text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 rounded" ng-model="comp" ng-change="item1=comp;item2=comp;item3=comp;item4=comp;title.name=comp; " ng-model="inputText" />
                        <div>
                            <small class="text-muted text-left">Search Keywords: Smoke alarm, Power point installation, Emergency, etc...</small>
                        </div>
                       <!-- <select name="show-filter" ng-model="catFilter" ng-options="category as categories for category in categories">
                        </select>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="x in myData | filter: comp | filter: data" ng-bind-html="x.title.name  | highlightMatch:data">
                    <div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron text-center rounded-0">

                            <!--<p ng-class="(x.title.bckColour=== currentColor ? 'electrical' : 'data') + ' ' + (true ? 'electrical' : 'data')">{{x.title.name}}</p>-->
                            <a ng-href="/{{x.imgurl}}"><img class="img-responsive center-block" ng-src="{{x.img}}" /></a>
                            <p ng-class="(x.title.bckColour=='electrical') ? 'electrical center-block' : 'data center-block'">{{x.title.name}}</p>
                            <ul class="jumboBackground">
                                <a ng-href="/{{x.item1.url}}"><li>{{x.item1.name}}</li></a>
                                <a ng-href="/{{x.item2.url}}"><li>{{x.item2.name}}</li></a>
                                <a ng-href="/{{x.item3.url}}"><li>{{x.item3.name}}</li></a>
                                <a ng-href="/{{x.item4.url}}"><li>{{x.item4.name}}</li></a>
                                <a ng-href="https://sharpe-ers.com.au/book-easy" ng-class="(x.title.bckColour=='electrical') ? 'elecButton' : 'dataButton'"class=" btn-new center-block  btn-lg ">BOOK NOW</a>
                            </ul>
                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the array in "ng-bind-html='x.title.name'", I have used ng-init directive to create a variable and assign array attribute to it. Below is how I was able to do it on one array element: Similarly, I have followed the same with other array elements separately.

Something like this : 
HTML View :

`<p ng-class="(x.title.bckColour=='electrical') ? 'electrical center-block' : 'data center-block'" ng-init="text= x.title.name" ng-bind-html=" text | highlight:search" >{{x.title.name}}</p>`

And I have written JS code, which replaces the search term with span tag to add background colour to highlight the search text. As we can see in the JS file.

```js
app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="x in myData | filter: search " >
                    <div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron text-center rounded-0">
                        
                            <!--<p ng-class="(x.title.bckColour=== currentColor ? 'electrical' : 'data') + ' ' + (true ? 'electrical' : 'data')">{{x.title.name}}</p>-->
                            <a ng-href="/{{x.imgurl}}"><img class="img-responsive center-block" ng-src="{{x.img}}" /></a>
                            <p ng-class="(x.title.bckColour=='electrical') ? 'electrical center-block' : 'data center-block'" ng-init="text= x.title.name" ng-bind-html=" text | highlight:search" >{{x.title.name}}</p>
            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```